# file command output -- linux version

Tags: linux, chroot

Why two executables are showing different version for linux. When cross-compiled compiled under chroot enviroment.

**GNU/Linux 3.6.3,

GNU/Linux 2.6.26,**

Hello world program output.

```
ignite@ignite:~/sbox2/rootfs/rfs-raspbian/home/pi$ file abc
abc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.6.3, not stripped
```

My server perogram output

```
/vscp/daemon/linux$ file vscpd
vscpd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x3f673b6fdb44e8aae68e278e70f9e020d225d794, not stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that they are compiled against different dynamic libraries. Issuing "readelf -l " should show you against which loader they are compiled.